# Using WhenAll pattern in Unity via UniRx?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using the UniRx package in Unity, one can use async-await. But what's the right way to convert something like the following (this example uses a GPT-3 www request, but it could be anything)

```
string result1 = await textAI.GetCompletion("Albeit Einstein was");
string result2 = await textAI.GetCompletion("Susan Sarandon is");
```

to something that launches the GetCompletion functions simultaneously, then continues when all finished and returned their result? E.g. using pseudo-code, like this:

```
string result1 = null;
string result2 = null;

await Task.WhenAll({
    result1 = await textAI.GetCompletion("Albeit Einstein was"),
    result2 = await textAI.GetCompletion("Susan Sarandon is")
});

Debug.Log("Results: " + result1 + ", " + result2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since it does what you need, any reason for not using Task.WhenAll?

Comment: UniRx was written in a time (~2014) when Unity was still using .NET CLR 2 and didn't have access `async/await` and [other .NET 4.x goodies that we now have access to in Unity 2017.1+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/unity-scripting-upgrade).  Apart from that, I don't think it's a good idea to add a _white-collar-business-software-pattern_ like _IoC_ to a **game**.  You want to avoid delegates at the best of times due to their potential for memory-leaks and having parts of your code executed unpredictably outside of normal Unity flow is a concern.

Comment: Yeah all that too, I work on a project using UniRx and that has been one of the worst decision our lead made. Code looks fancy and all but it's a major gamble, especially when it has not been updated for 3 years.

Comment: "Since it does what you need, any reason for not using Task.WhenAll?" @Everts How would I do that in Unity? Thanks!

Comment: @MickyD It's great to hear it should already work in Unity, but then what is the meaning of [this video at the provided timestamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SBP2Gpm97k&t=1147s), where in 2022 the Unity official say that providing a unified async await is among the "next steps"? (Also see the slides that follows.) In either case, what code would I use then for above example? Thanks!

Comment: "Apart from that, I don't think it's a good idea to add a white-collar-business-software-pattern like IoC to a game." @MickyD What would you suggest for the WhenAll pattern then, which I need in my app to launch several GPT-3 & StableDiffusion www requests at once, while waiting for all of them to complete before the next step? (For example, I may need 2 simultaneous different GPT-3 web requests, each analyzing a different part of the user speech input, from sentiment analysis to determine the facial expression, to extraction an action plan to go on a mission.) Thanks!

Comment: It simply means that the Unity _API_ is not making any/full use of `async/await` **not** that Unity is preventing _you_ from writing your own asynchronous code using `async/await`. Unity has its own async as well as coroutines.  I wouldn't be terribly worried, much of the Unity API specially anything to do with the GPU (e.g. [textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-allowThreadedTextureCreation.html)) must always be done on the Primary Unity thread.  This is common in ALL GUI frameworks whether it's the Windows GUI, Mac, DirectX or OpenGL.

Comment: _"What would you suggest for the WhenAll pattern"_ - I see no problem using `await Task.WhenAll()` as defined in .NET 4.x.   You can also use old-school `AutoResetEvent`/`ManualResetEvent` as the latter is easier for _peeking to see whether the job(s) is/are done without blocking._

Comment: I just removed UniRx from the project and it all still works (as long as I kept a static Extensions class with their `TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter` addition) so that's great!

Comment: _"This is common in ALL GUI frameworks whether it's the Windows GUI, Mac, `DirectX` or OpenGL"_ - I seem to remember a few years back NVidia playing with the idea of a new low-level, low-overhead API allowing devs direct access to the GPU with threads!  Though I might have dreamt it. ;)

Comment: (All questions have been answered now as per the accepted answer, thanks everyone!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the existing Task.WhenAll

```
async void Start()
{
    Task<string> a =  AsyncRoutineA(); // Here no await, you want the Task object
    Task<string> b =  AsyncRoutineB();
    await Task.WhenAll(a, b); // add all tasks and await that one
    Debug.Log(a.Result + " " + b.Result);
}


async Task<string> AsyncRoutineA()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "A Done";
}

async Task<string> AsyncRoutineB()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "B Done";
}
```

UniRx would do the same, with extra overhead so that you'd get an Observable object that you'd not use in this context.

You can do the same with coroutines:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    string resultA = null;
    string resultB = null;
    StartCoroutine(AsyncRoutineA((result) => resultA = result));
    StartCoroutine(AsyncRoutineA((result) => resultB = result));
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultA) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultB);
    });
    Debug.Log(resultA + " " + resultB);
}


IEnumerator AsyncRoutineA(Action<string> result)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    result.Invoke("A done");
}

IEnumerator AsyncRoutineB(Action<string> result)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    result.Invoke("B done");
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you so much! (UniRx is now removed from my project.)